# mySQL hierarchical grouping sort

Tags: mysql

I have a schema that essentially looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` text,
  `type` tinyint(4),
  `parent` int(10)
)
```

The `type` field is just an enum where 1 is a parent type, and 2 is a child type (in actuality there are many types, where some should behave like parents and some like children).  The `parent` field indicates that a record is the child of another record.

I know this is probably not ideal for the query I want to build, but this is what I have to work with.

I would like to sort and group the data so that the parent records are sorted by `title`, and grouped under each parent is the child records sorted by `title`.  Like so:

```
 ID | title       |type |parent 
--------------------------------
 4  | ParentA     | 1   |
 2  | ChildA      | 2   | 4
 5  | ChildB      | 2   | 4
 7  | ParentB     | 1   |
 9  | ChildC      | 2   | 7
 1  | ChildD      | 2   | 7
```

---

** **Edit** **

We should be able to take the `type` field out of the picture entirely.  If `parent` is not null then it should be grouped underneath it's parent.

Comment: Is this a 2-level hierarchy or an arbitrarily-deep tree?

Comment: @Eric, just a simple 2-level hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `data` ORDER BY COALESCE(`parent`, `id`), `parent`, `id`
```

Comment: This seems nice and clean... I don't suppose the sorting by `title` requirement can be  worked into the ORDER BY clause can it?

Comment: Got this to work, thanks for the lead!  `ORDER BY COALESCE (IF(parentID, parentTitle, NULL), IF(ID, title, NULL)), parentID, title`  -- Works in my actual query because I have a join that gives me the `parentTitle` which I can then swap into the COALESCE if needed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice the `title` requirement.

Comment: 8 years later and i just came across this, how the h*ll does this work?! Thanks nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution tested to work on SQL Server.  Should be essentially the same on MySQL

```
select Id, Title, [Type], Id as OrderId from Hier h1 where [Type] = 1
union
select Id, Title, [Type], Parent as OrderId from Hier h2 where [Type] = 2
order by OrderId, [Type]
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you wanted it to sort on the titles, correct?

```
SELECT id, title, parent
FROM
  ( SELECT id, title, parent,
    CASE WHEN parent is null THEN title ELSE CONCAT((SELECT title FROM `data` d2 WHERE d2.id = d.parent), '.', d.title) END AS sortkey
    FROM `data` d
   ) subtable
ORDER BY sortkey
```

edit: Edited to remove `type` from the query.

Comment: Doing the string concatination and sorting on that result is fairly inefficient.