# How to retrieve hierarchial parent-child data related by multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, join, hierarchical-data

I have a website that contains guitar lessons and exercises, broken down by category. So you could have category `scales`. Then a lesson `scales lesson1`, which could contain `exercise1_1`, `exercise1_2`. Likewise for other categories and lessons with exercises.

Lessons and exercises are considered nodes (it is a Drupal site). So there is a node table that has node ids, node type (lesson or exercise) and titles.

Other info fields for these nodes (lesson/exercise text, etc) are stored in separate tables for each field. For instance there is a `drupal_field_data_description` table that contains description for each lesson and exercise.

Categories are stored in a taxonomy `term` table.

Relations among categories are handled via a taxonomy index table that establishes child-parent relation (so you could have scales, scales->major scales, etc). **For my question, I am just considering one depth of category.**

Categories of lessons and exercises are stored in a table `drupal_field_data_field_category`, which maps lessons and exercises to the category they are a part of.

Exercise-Lesson child-parent relations are stored in a table `drupal_field_data_field_lesson` that maps exercises to lessons.

Here is example data:

The categories (drupal_taxonomy_term_data):

```
tid vid name
1   2   Scales
2   2   Arpeggios
```

The lessons and exercises (drupal_node):

```
nid type        title
1   lesson      Lesson1
2   lesson      Lesson2
3   exercise    Ex1_1
4   exercise    Ex1_2
5   exercise    Ex2_1
6   exercise    Ex2_2
```

The description field for the lessons and exercises (drupal_field_data_field_description):

```
entity_type     bundle   entity_id  field_description_value
node            lesson   1          Lesson1Summary
node            lesson   2          Lesson2Summary
node            exercise 3          Ex1_1Summary
node            exercise 4          Ex1_2Summary
node            exercise 5          Ex2_1Summary
node            exercise 6          Ex2_2Summary
```

The mapping of lessons and exercises to the taxonomy (drupal_taxonomy_index):

```
nid tid
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   1
```

The mapping of lessons and exercises to the category (drupal_field_data_field_category) (this one almost seems unnecessary because of the taxonomy index):

```
entity_type bundle   entity_id  field_category_tid
node        lesson   1          1
node        lesson   2          1
node        exercise 3          1
node        exercise 4          1
node        lesson   5          1
node        lesson   6          1
```

The mapping of exercises to lessons (drupal_field_data_field_lesson):

```
entity_type     bundle      entity_id   field_lesson_target_id
node            exercise    3           1
node            exercise    4           1
node            exercise    5           2
node            exercise    6           2
```

So... with this structure, I can't figure out how to build a query that will return a result of the form

```
Lesson1 Lesson1Summary
Ex1_1 Ex1_1Summary
Ex1_2 Ex1_2Summary
Lesson2 Lesson2Summary
Ex2_1 Ex2_1Summary
Ex2_2 Ex2_2Summary
```

Note that Lesson1 and Lesson2 are in the same category.

I need to return such data, because for a category page (that has no subcategories), I need to display a table for each lesson that shows the exercises in the lesson.

I could do all this in multiple queries, but I am really trying to better understand SQL joins and grouping. Also, I am not dead set on a result set as shown above. I am open to whatever result set will let me readily display the data (which I will do via PHP) in the fashion as I described.

The [SQL fiddle is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88f80/1)

How would you recommend building such a query to extract a lesson and its exercises grouped in a logical way (e.g. how I show above)?

Seems getting lesson and exercises in this way would amount to a self join, with a variety of inner joins on the other tables but I just can't piece it all together...

Answer (score 0):

Well, after much reading, I think I figured it out:

```
SELECT n.title, d.field_description_value, n.nid, l.field_lesson_target_id from drupal_node n

JOIN drupal_field_data_field_description AS d ON d.entity_id = n.nid

JOIN drupal_taxonomy_index AS t ON t.nid = n.nid

LEFT JOIN drupal_field_data_field_lesson AS l ON l.entity_id = n.nid

ORDER BY COALESCE(l.field_lesson_target_id, n.nid), l.field_lesson_target_id, n.nid
```

I based above on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000643/mysql-hierarchical-grouping-sort)

My [sqlfiddle is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88f80/10).

This is definitely new territory for me, and while above works, I wish I understood the ORDER BY and GROUP BY nuances to understand where/how to use them.